# Как вырезать из массива ячейку по определенному ключу?

Tags: массивы, php

Например, есть переменная $name и массив например из 5 ячеек. Как найти ту ячейку имя которой находится в переменной $name, не перебирая весь массив? Необходимо вырезать ячейку в переменную. Пожалуйста, подскажите есть-ли такая функция?

Comment: $array[$name] ? Это самые основы...

Comment: и тут я понял, что двух мерный массив это матрица ...  Как меня зае**** эти массивы.

Comment: массив в массиве в массиве